# How to create my own "sudo" program?

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to create "my own" `sudo` command (for my file manager/commander written in C++/OpenGL). Please help provide necessary steps and things to consider. I know it has something to do with `suid` bit, but that's all I know so far.

Comment: Sorry, but this is far too broad to be answered. Basically it asks: Tell me everything about programming and where to start reading. This place is _not_ a tutorial place or a general "how to get started" forum. It is to ask _specific_ questions about _specific_ issues in ones own code.

Comment: If this question is a reflection of your current capabilities then you shouldn't consider writing your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about filesystem flags. You have only to ensure that:

1. The executable file does belongs to root
2. It has the suid flag in the file system (you can set it with chattr u+s).

After you do that, it will be executed with root permissions even when running from a regular user.

Please also note that you can get an UID which had actually ran the program by calling getuid(), while geteuid() will always evaluate to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to you to download sudo command code and modify it based on your requirement